# swift enum get the associated value of multiple case with same parameters in single switch-case

Tags: ios, swift

Here is a common enum with associated values.

```
enum MultiplierType {
    case width(Double)
    case height(Double)
    case xxxxx1(Double)
    case xxxxx2(Double)
    case xxxxx3(Double)

    var value: Double {
        switch self {
            // Normal way.
            case let .width(value):
                return value
            case let .height(value):
                return value
            case let .xxxxx1(value):
                return value
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how to do like this?

```
var value: Double {
    switch self {
    // How to get the value in one case?
    case let .width(value), .height(value), .xxx:
         return value
    }
}
```

Or

```
var value: Double {
    switch self {
    // How to get the value in one case?
    case let .width, .height, .xxx (value):
         return value
    }
}
```

What is the most elegant way to get the associated value?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can put multiple enum values in the same `case` line, but you have to move the `let` into the `()`:

```
var value: Double {
    switch self {
    case .width(let value), .height(let value), .xxxxx1(let value):
         return value
    }
}
```

You might want to put each `enum` value on a separate line:

```
var value: Double {
    switch self {
    case .width(let value),
         .height(let value),
         .xxxxx1(let value):
         return value
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, that's about as elegant as it gets with `enum`s with associated values.  There's no way to get the associated value without explicitly listing the `enum`s.

You can only combine values in the same line that have the same type of associated value, and all of the values have to bind to the same variable name.  That way, in the code that follows, you know that the `value` is bound and what its type is no matter which `enum` pattern matched.

Comment: Do we have any idea why `default(let value)` cannot be used?

Comment: It is necessary to use pattern matching to extract the associated value of an enum case.  `default` is a keyword and not a pattern.  Perhaps Swift be extended to implement `case _(let value)` to match any value that has one associated value, but it doesn't do that currently.  It's an interesting idea though.