# Using Enum associated values in ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swift

I want my enum be Identifiable so made this code:

```
enum ShapeEnum: Identifiable {

    case rectangle(size: CGSize, color: Color, id: UUID = UUID())
    case circle(size: CGFloat, color: Color, id: UUID = UUID())
    
    var id: UUID {
        return self.id
    }
}
```

but Xcode show a warring of:

> Function call causes an infinite recursion

Not sure why or how i can do it better, but my code should just works I think... However I changed my code to:

```
 var id: UUID {
    switch self {
    case .rectangle(_, _, let id):
        return id
    case .circle(_, _, let id):
        return id
    }
}
```

But I it looks not ok I think, I just need to return id and I do not need to do (_, _, let id), so how can I do better?

Comment: Your implementation with `switch` is what you need to do. You can't simply return `id` since the enum itself does not have an `id` property. The computed property is only value because all of the enum's cases happen to have an `id` associated value that you can return.

Comment: But each case has id.

Comment: The fact that each case happens to have an `id` associated value is not at all the same as the enum itself having an `id`. Your `id` computed property is just a convenience for all users of the enum to get the case's `id` associated value.

Comment: Hmmm, can I or should I code like that, that each case confirm to Identifiable? I mean each case not the enum itself.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030390/swift-enum-get-the-associated-value-of-multiple-case-with-same-parameters-in-sin for some explanation about why you need to explicitly enumerate each case.

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following seems to work:

```swift
enum ShapeEnum: Identifiable {
    case rectangle(size: CGSize, color: Color, id: UUID = UUID())
    case circle(size: CGSize, color: Color, id: UUID = UUID())
    var id: UUID {
        switch self {
        case .rectangle(_, _, let id), .circle(_, _, let id):
            return id
        }
    }
}

let circle: ShapeEnum = .circle(size: .zero, color: Color.accentColor)
let rectangle: ShapeEnum = .circle(size: .zero, color: Color.accentColor)
```

Just added a small difference in the `switch` statement, but it's basically the same, and the best that I can think of.

EDIT:
Enums are cool.